# Wondering what exactly is comparing here?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> When French Director Michel Hazanavicius’s film ‘The Search’ was screened it was greeted with both boos and cheers.
>   The subject is the second Chechen war and is as different from his previous offering, “The Artist” as you can get – much to the annoyance of some of his critics and fans.

Source: http://euronews.com/2014/05/22/controversy-in-cannes-as-the-film-the-search-is-booed-and-cheered/

You can get much to ? 
I know the use of  **as ...as** .
I understand that it is saying that the new film is as much different as previous film, but the last part is the place I drew a blank !

Comment: I think it would read a lot easier if there were a comma after "The Artist". I daresay they should have a comma there.

Answer (score 1):

The *as ... as* construction and the *much to* phrase should be parsed separately.

> The subject is ... as different from ... *The Artist* as you can get

This compares the subject of *The Search* to that of the *The Artist* and states the the difference is the greatest you can get:  “You cannot get a subject more different than *The Artist*”.

> ...—much to the annoyance of some of his critics and fans.

The *much to NOUN* idiom is a sentential modifier meaning approximately that the eventuality described in the sentence “caused much *(or great)* NOUN”.

> Much to my dismay, I found that someone had stolen my wallet. ... *The theft caused me much dismay*.
>   John returned uninjured in November, 1918, much to the joy of his family. ... *His return caused his family much joy*.

So in your example, the author states that the great difference in subject between Hazanavicius’ two films greatly annoyed some critics and fans, who doubtless hoped that the second film would be more like the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Much to the annoyance here is describing that his critics and fans loved The Artist, and they were annoyed that his new film is completely different.

The word much here increases the amount of annoyance felt by the critics and fans, really emphasising the point the author wishes to make.

He could have simply said..."to the annoyance of some of his critics and fans" but he decided to make it more emphatic by using the determiner "Much"